# Accountancy forum or q&a (I have question about state budget)

Tags: economics

Hi,

this Q&A is about personal finance but I need to find a forum or Q&A where I could ask questions about state budget and that kind of accountancy.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

For SE sites, there are two proposals:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5477/us-politics

Also, read this discussion: [Clarifying the Area 51 proposal: Can some basic economics and policy questions be on-topic?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148/clarifying-the-area-51-proposal-can-some-basic-economics-and-policy-questions-be) - maybe your question is OK for this site too.